# Strange unexpected elements when baking texture

Tags: texture-baking, photogrammetry

[image]

Hello!

I am baking a texture from a high-poly photogrammetry model to a low-poly and I get those strange beige spots.

What am I doing wrong?

(see my baking setting on the side)

Thanks for your feedback!
[image]

[image]

model with the seams

Comment: Could it be that lowpoly is protruding out of highpoly in those same places? Increase extrusion then a bit or create a cage for baking. You can [edit] the question with screenshots of objects in viewport (solid shading). Also apply modifiers if any before baking. Additinally double check UV map to make sure none of islands overlap

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The lowpoly/highpoly are not perfectly overlapping, but it doesn't match the beige spots. I did apply the modifiers. No island is overlapping... :)
I will soon add a picture, so you can see how the overlapping looks.

About the cage, since my model is almost flat I am not sure how I can do a cage, I though the extrusion option would do as good. One thing I notice is that the spots only appear on the surface that are perpendicular to the main surface.

Comment: It's weird since additionally now it seems spots you mention on the second to last screenshot changed their shape and repeat wireframe pattern. Try also to recalculate normals in edit mode of that area (or see if any are red with viewport overlays > face orientation). Maybe you could share the file on https://pasteall.org/blend/ if anyone is ready to run some debugging

Comment: I explain one workflow (and some pitfalls) in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nygpWWJTcQs&t=33s

Comment: @MrZak Yes you're right the spots are slightly different, I think that I changed the extrusion distance between the 2 pictures, maybe the texture interpolation as well.

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz thanks for your tutorial, it is well done. I followed a method similar to yours (I didn't use the emission technique tho' but I have 18 slots on my highpoly model and I don't see any extra lights/shadows when baking from the diffuse/color bake type).

Comment: If my extrusion was too long I believe that it's the asphalt color or the grass color that should leak on my stones. The beige spots look a bit like the sand that is on my model on another place but very far away (and it's hard to say that it really look the same)

Comment: @MrZak my model is more than 500 mb plus the textures are more than 200 mb, I'm not sure how I can send you that. Maybe I can put a zip file in onedrive or such...

Comment: So I made a zip file with the models and the textures. Here is the link:
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuGa8VHo3JfFtApq_5U1Qz_9mntg?e=axwVWj
Let me know if anything seems like the source of the problem...

Comment: @MrZak also I forgot to say that there wasn't any face orientation issues